# Use columns in ActiveAdmin form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin on my Rails project. How can I stylize the form view of a resource using `columns` like in the show view inside `has_many` relation (by columns, I mean to have two or three distincts bloc of floating content) ?

Here is the code I tried to setup (I used .arb views):

```
f.inputs t('activerecord.models.slide.other') do
  f.has_many :slides, heading: false do |item|

    # I would like to be a first column
    item.input :image,
                 as: :file,
                 label: I18n.t('form.label.slide'),
                 hint: retina_image_tag(item.object, :image, :preview)
    item.input :online,
                 as: :boolean,
                 hint: I18n.t('form.hint.slide.online')

    if item.object.self_image?
      item.input :_destroy,
                   as: :boolean,
                   hint: I18n.t('form.hint.slide.destroy')
    end

    # I would like to be a second column
    item.translated_inputs 'Translated fields', switch_locale: true do |t|
      t.input :title, hint: I18n.t('form.hint.title')
      t.input :description,
                hint: I18n.t('form.hint.content')
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I finally made it working erasing ActiveAdmin css as it was wrote in a previous answer. Thanks

Comment: could you maybe post a brief solution? So that others can benefit.

Comment: Sure, I just add a custom CSS to erase AA default form styling. So I targeted my element and I applied a float: left and a width of half screen size. `#active_admin_content form.slider fieldset > ol li fieldset.inputs.has_many_fields > ol > li.input
  float: left
  clear: none
  width: 47%

  &:nth-child(2)
    float: right

  &:not(.input)
    clear: both` (Sorry, I can't write better the sass style, SO doesn't allow it)

Answer (score 2):

add a custom CSS to erase AA default form styling. 
Apply a float: left and a width of half screen size.

```sass
    #active_admin_content 
      form.slider
        fieldset > ol
          li
            fieldset.inputs.has_many_fields > ol > li.input
              float: left
              clear: none
              width: 47% 
            &:nth-child(2)
              float: right
            &:not(.input)
              clear: both
```